# Angular/Rxjs - a more specific operator than map() when converting a response object to an array

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a service where my code does work. The problem is want to use a better operator than map() to convert the response object to an array of objects. I have tried toArray() but that seems to wrap the whole response into an array. Any Ideas? See the code below:

```
getCurrencies() {
const params = new HttpParams().set("key", this.key);
return this.http.get(this.url, { params }).pipe(
  map(resp => {
    const postArry = [];
    for (const key in resp) {
      if (resp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        postArry.push({ ...resp[key] });
      }
    }
    return postArry.slice(0, 30);
  })
);
```

}

Comment: show us the format of incoming data and transformed data

Comment: @Bemi, you'd like to split every property of **resp** to objects and push them to array?

Comment: just create your own operator if you have some repeating object to array work, it is quite straight forward to do

Comment: Isn't that just `map(resp => resp.values.slice(30))`